# Using an Airport Extreme vs an Airport Express to extend network

Tags: airport

I would like to add an additional airport to extend my wireless network.
I'm trying to decide between another 5th generation airport extreme (A1408) and a 3rd generation airport express (A1392)

Is there any benefits to using one over the other? I know the express has a 3.5mm audio jack, is there anything else? How does the performance compare?

Comment: Extreme has wireless ac at 1200mbps and express only has n at 300mbps. Performance at a gigabit speed on the Ac network would be better compared to an n network, assuming you have newer devices.

Comment: Are you sure about the ac on the 5th gen? I thought that was only the 6th?